# Connection string keyword 'data sourse' is not supported. For a possible alternative

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite

I build project my with WPF and entity framework and lately I changed it from MySQL to SQLite and I installed

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.Core
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools
```

And I make Database Migrate in MyDbContext but when I run it shows this error

```
'Connection string keyword 'data source' is not supported. For a possible alternative, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2142181.'
```

Comment: my string connection "Data Sourse=test.sqlite"

Comment: It is wrong spelled. It is 'Data Source'

Comment: i fixed it and show another error SQLite Error 1: 'no such table: Members'.   may i need to create sqlite file !! or they create it own

Comment: Probably another typo, just check if the table exists in your db. The creation of the file depends highly on what you're working on

Comment: the project was work fie with mysql thay do migration with Database.MigrateAsync(); but here not and i test this commande to do migration add-migration first and no resualt

Comment: i changesDatabase.MigrateAsync(); with  Database.Migrate(); the they work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this instead

```
Data Source=test.sqlite
```

Answer (score 0):

Your connection string is not true. There is a typo error. It will be Source, not Sourse!

```
 Data Source=test.sqlite
```